# How to debug "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException" errors in PHP (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, debugging, timeout

I am getting reports of many errors encountered by clients

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
>
> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I, myself, cannot replicate it on my local machine nor on the production server. The URLs for this are all throughout the site, so, I guess it's something global, like a Middleware that's causing this.

I am using [Sentry.io](http://sentry.io/) to collect the data, but the exception trace only has 1 entry that points to a certain code in the `Symfony` base code, most commonly:

> vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php at line 73
>
> vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php at line 45
>
> vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php at line 69

Clearly it seems there is something related to the file system, but due to no trace I cannot see where to look for the mistake in the site code. I would guess it is some kind of infinite loop or leak, but there is no trace to look at it, and no consistent way to reproduce the problem.

How should I be looking for the problem and debugging this?

Are there any settings I could set, or tools I could use/enable?

Comment: When you say, `I, myself, cannot replicate it on my local machine nor on the production server` have you tried it using a client account that experienced the issues.  A lot of these look like file directory iterations, if you allow them to upload or generate files, they may have too many files and by having an account without any you wont be able to reproduce the issue.  Just a thought.

Comment: Do you have access to the command line? If so you could try strace https://www.tecmint.com/strace-commands-for-troubleshooting-and-debugging-linux/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes, I tried with various session variables (non-logged in, logged in as different users). There is no file upload/generation in the system, and the errors randomly occur as the user is trying to open even the simplest page that fetches some basic data.

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez I will give that a go, thanks.

Comment: Error messages normally have a trace back to the main piece of code that called all the string of function/classes look for the place the error started, it will almost definitely be in code you/someone wrote and not in the Symfony code base

Comment: @RiggsFolly As I've mentioned, the trace stack only includes this last piece.

Comment: Did you look in the error log in `var/logs`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the exceptions are the same as they are collected in `Sentry`, and containing the same trace with only 1 item.

Comment: Is your filesystem local or network attached?

Comment: @alariva It's local

Comment: So the problem araises for your client only in production. Right? Do you have or can you gather any accurate info on when does this happen? What actions was he performing? Timestamps? Logs? Occurrence frecuency?

Comment: @alariva Yes I have precise logs of this happening, but cannot replicate it myself, that's why it is so random and hard to debug. I have over 1000 records of exactly when and what URLs are requested. However, I make the same request over the production server via various session variable combinations and would only get the error once in thousands or so requests.

Comment: So narrowing down might require to methodically record every occurrence (both error and success) of the same trigger action and then compare the context conditions. If its filesystem, do you know if your host is running on hdd or sdd? Any chance of hw or partition failure?

Comment: @alariva I've tried to do a quick script that would send x requests to an URL, but that did not prove effective (all requests passed). It's hosted on AWS servers so I would think they would have hdd failure checks. I will check the dash panel for anything in that alley but it's a really long shot :/

Comment: I see. Is it possible to you to provide any background on what the app does and what kind of operation is performed by tye user when issue araises?

Comment: @alariva The app is an extremely basic e-commerce site where people choose a product and pay for it. That's the tough thing, the issue arises on all kinds of requests, including simply opening the homepage, getting their order information, and even some AJAX requests (to get cart etc.).

Comment: Looks like an i/o problem, possibly raised when trying to access cache or any other resource on disk. I also think its weird on aws, but at this point we cant discard this. Can you post your .env? (Remive all tokens and credentials first) and the composer.json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177767/discussion-between-giedrius-and-alariva).

Comment: I think you are making some API call which is causing a problem.

Comment: @Giedrius Any update on this issue? Also, kindly include your full dev-ops stack in the question.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on the same issue at the moment. Did you succeed in solving it somehow by any chance? If so, could you please share? If not, maybe we could cooperate and find some answers together?

Comment: @dardvas Hi, I did not find a clear solution to this really, I just had to debug the code bit by bit to find where the issue was, I think it was a memory leak in my case.

Comment: @Giedrius seems like for me it was too many cache files, stored in a filesystem. Moving them to Redis, as IlGala said solved the problem. Well, your question and it's answers make up a nice checklist for anyone else facing this issue :)

Comment: @dardvas That's good to know, thanks! I will mark that answer as I do also believe that it is the more likely cause and the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading your chat conversation, I saw that you're using this `.env` configuration:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file 
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

I think this is the problem... I explain myself a little better.

When you use the `file` driver for the cache or the session, Laravel will create tons of files that stores users session data or application cache data...

If your e-commerce is growing and generating a lot of traffic, then it may be possible that the performance are slowing down because of this tons of files that has to be scanned by the framework.

I think that may be two possible solutions:

- Your production environment has to be upgraded (I don't know your production server specs or if you have enough resources).
- The file driver it's becoming too slow for your application requirements.

I usually use [redis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis#configuration) as cache and session driver, it's faster and with a good strategy for "smart caching" it's a great tool.

I think you should try to use it aswell if possibile. [Memcached](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#driver-prerequisites) may be a good solution too.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will try to fix my problem using your and @elitepc answers (`register_shudown_function`) and see where that takes me, thanks!

Comment: the question is "How to debug timeout errors in PHP (Laravel)?", the app should work with this config CACHE_DRIVER=file SESSION_DRIVER=file, of course it is better to use redis but that is not the question here...

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about the reason of the exception then you can handle it in two ways

1
    increase request timeout 
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); //60 seconds = 1 minute

2 wrap your code in try catch

```
try{
  //logic goes here
}catch(\Excaption $e){
 Log::error($e->getMessage().' '. $e->getFile().' '. $e->getLine());
 return back()->with('error',$e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: 1. I think increasing the timeout might be a temporary solution but will not fix the root cause. 2. Do you mean to wrap the whole application (in `index.php` or `bootstrap.php`)? If so, that does not produce any different results, the same exception is just handled manually.

Answer (score 2):

Can you register a shutdown function?
The shutdown function is called even when a timeout occurs. With it you can print or save the what you want to a log file.
I'm not sure if there is a better way to get the backtrace in laravel, but that's how I'd probably do in pure php (calling debug_backtrace).

```
<?php

function timedOut() {
    //save to a log file instead of printing
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

register_shutdown_function("timedOut");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Was not aware of this, will definitely give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not used to Laravel but I have had this issue where I solved it by using PHP's register_shutdown_function.

I have found it to be very useful in tracking errors which occur randomly.
This is how I do this in my code. You could put this somewhere in a common file that would execute on every page, index.php would be a good option for you as all Laravel routes go through it (my assumption).

```
register_shutdown_function( "check_for_fatal" );

function check_for_fatal(){
    $time = time(); //time when this error occurred

    $error = error_get_last();
    if (in_array($error["type"], [E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR])){
        $email_body = [];
        $email_body[] = 'Date: ' . date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $time);
        ob_start();
        var_dump($error);
        $email_body[] = ob_get_clean();
        //include any other data as needed
        //$body[] = "add data as appropriate";

        //You can email it to yourself, but if there are lots of errors you will be bombarded with emails
        mail('your_email_address@example.com', 'Subject', implode("\r\n", $email_body));
       //or you can save this to some log file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PHP is waiting for some resource, eg. file access, database, mail server (I think file).

- Did you try using your app on many tabs with one session?
- Did you try login to same account from many machines?
- Maybe some part of script is opening file and not closing it?
- Did you track user actions from opening site to get this error?
- Check your production database - maybe have very small limit of connections?

**EDIT**

I see that you are using `dannyvankooten/vat.php` library which makes some requests to external services. This can be a source of your problems. This library is making requests using curl. Author is setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` but `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is not set and your script sometimes can wait longer than it is limited by `max_execution_time` setting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should increase the timeout just yet. if you do the "try catch" you might get an understanding of the underlying problem. If not, check the operations / functions performed in the specific method or class. There is a chance that you are querying a huge table and maybe trying to use the information.

if you do

```
\DB::listen(function ($sql) {
        var_dump($sql);
   });
```

this will give you an indication of how many queries are running for the operation

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to catch this in a try catch as it's actually a PHP error rather than an exception.

To be able to debug this, you have a couple of options:

1. Add some logs in the code to identify where it times out
2. You can use the [Laravel dump server package](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server) to dump out logs. This is actually going to be shipped with Laravel 5.7 but you can always add the package for now

Answer (score 0):

I installed laravel-debugbar.I think  it  help you.

composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Next open config/app.php and inside the ‘providers’ array add:

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
```

in alias array class:

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
```

and you can view

```
Debugbar::measure('My long operation', function() {
```

// Do something…
});

Answer (score 0):

You can not catch php timeout error. This error occur when php interpreter stop execution. You can only increase time limit e.g ini_set('max_execution_time', 300) or convert long execution work to a cron job e.g  laravel task schedule.

Answer (score 0):

A New **sentry** version will give you a proper stack trace.

You must use **"getsentry/sentry-php"** version >= "2.0"

- Here is issue where is reported : https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/issues/761
- Here is the PR for fix : https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/pull/763

Answer (score -1):

In all honesty, your best call is to install xdebug and just debug it old school way, go through the whole request to find a bottleneck and try to figure out where does it come from. Laravel, as well as other frameworks, were designed to run as smoothly as possible. If you're facing any errors of this kind it means you might have just code something incorrectly.

It's also difficult to give you a specific advice without more information. What I would propose is it recreate the specs of the environment (you can use Docker or Vagrant or whatever comes to your mind that would work) that your Laravel app is facing and then run with xdebug to find where the problem lies.